# Error and wrong behaviour on close component from parent using Vuetify v-dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've a component with a simple `v-dialog` to show a message to user and a `v-btn` to close it. The scenario is:

1. User click on the button that show `v-dialog`'s component.
2. User click on the `v-btn` to close the component
3. A error is triggered on console: `Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "show"`
4. If click again on the button to open dialog, the dialog is not re-open, because the `data() show` not change the value from the component's `v-btn`.

The dialog component **BasicMessageDialog.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-dialog v-if="showDialog" width="500">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title primary-title class="title">Ops...</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text class="body-1">{{message}}</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn text color="primary" @click="show = false" class="body-1">Beleza!</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BasicMessageDialog",
  computed: {
    showDialog() {
      return this.show;
    }
  },
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
    message: String
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The main component **Login.vue**

```
<template>
...
 <BasicMessageDialog :message="messageBasicDialog" :show="showBasicMessageDialog">
...
</BasicMessageDialog>
</template>

<script>
import BasicMessageDialog from "@/components/BasicMessageDialog";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    BasicMessageDialog
  },
data: () => ({
      showBasicMessageDialog: false,
      messageBasicDialog: "",
)},
methods: {
    forgetPassword() {
      console.log("forgetPassword");
      if (this.email == "") {
        this.messageBasicDialog = "Digite o e-mail no campo!";
        this.showBasicMessageDialog = true;
      }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your updating the show prop in your dialog component wherein your show data was came from your parent. That's why it is returning a warning of `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.`

To solve your issue, here are some ways to prevent that  warning.

**First** when you clicked the dialog button or clicked on the outside of your dialog, you must emit an event in your dialog component. like this one.

in your `V-dialog component`. when user clicked on a button

```
<v-btn text color="primary" @click="this.$emit('hideModal')" class="body-1">Beleza!</v-btn>
```

Now in your parent component should received this event. Parent Component like this

```
<BasicMessageDialog :message="messageBasicDialog" :show="showBasicMessageDialog" @hideModal='showBasicMessageDialog = false'>
...
</BasicMessageDialog>
```

Now, the issue again is what if the user clicked the outside part of dialog not the button ? To solve this you must watch the value of show prop. like this one. `In your v-dialog` component put this.

```
watch: {
   show(val) {
      if(!val) {
         this.$emit('hideModal')
      }
   }
}
```

And everything will work fine now.

**Second** is to use vue .sync modifier

> For convenience, Vue js offer a shorthand for this pattern with the
> .sync modifier. Please read the docs here [sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html). This approach will let you avoid emitting event. Unfortunately, true two-way binding can create maintenance issues.

**Last** is to use state management, vuex

> It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an
> application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in. docs here [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)
> a predictable fashion.

Comment: Solved. But, I had to remove the `this`. `<v-btn text color="primary" @click="$emit('hideModal')" class="body-1">Beleza!</v-btn>`. With `this` I got the follow error: `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this is null"`

Comment: ah okay sorry, yes you have to remove this.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <v-btn text color="primary" @click="show = false" class="body-1">Beleza!</v-btn>
```

You can't change prop as said in error instead of you have to add function, send it as prop, and call when you need change your prop value , parent have to handle the function and change data.

```
<template>
    ...
 <BasicMessageDialog :message="messageBasicDialog" :show="showBasicMessageDialog" :hide="showBasicMessageDialog=!showBasicMessageDialog">
...
</BasicMessageDialog>
</template>
```

and

```
<v-btn text color="primary" @click="hide" class="body-1">Beleza!</v-btn>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: I can't reproduce your solution, please improve your answer.